# How do you SSH from your desktop?

Tags: ssh

I am use to using putty and entering a hostname and key file and connecting. This is simple.

I am trying to follow this guide http://www.stackiq.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/AWS_Rocks_EC2_Tutorial_20111004.pdf and am on the step "SSH into the Frontend of your Cluster".

I dont have a mac nor the seen terminal program seen in the tutorial...how do I start a session on my desktop and SSH into the node I have created?

I already tried entering the host name of my server and my keyfile into putty and it is giving me "Server rejected key." Then I used putty to go into an existing separate server I have and tried to SSH into the new server. This accepted the key but then I couldnt do anything else bc it didnt recognize the location of the key on the old server once SSH has changed to the new server.

Thought?

Comment: Tell us which operating system you are using if it isn't Mac OS X.

Comment: Use the Putty Agent and enable 'agent forwarding' in the Putty session settings.

Comment: i am using windows 7

Comment: where is that option under?

Comment: Connection -> SSH -> Auth

Comment: Ok found it...is this to connect via another server's SSH session or connect direct from my desktop? I ask bc I just tried the later and no luck connecting...with using 'root' for username it just prompted me for a password (leaving it empty didnt work) and with username ec2-user it rejected my key.

Comment: Many SSH servers will not allow root login at all. Log in as an ordinary user instead. (You can use `sudo` later.)

Comment: The default login for all amazon EC2 instances is ec2-user, I tried this, it rejects my key. I have connect thousands of times to instances I made with this config...but it will not work with this prebuilt EC2, what really confuses me is that root does work if I SSH from another servers SSH. Thoughts?

Comment: When I tried using EC2 (still prefer linode.com) the key that was provided was for pure SSH on *nix or Mac - for Windows and Putty you had to (have to?) convert the key